# Connect from host to sandbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have a sandbox system setup using Oracle VM VirtualBox running on CentOS 6 what I want tho is to connect from my physical machine to the VM via SSH is there any easy ways to do that?

The VM is connected to the internet using NAT.

Comment: How is the guest connected to the world? Bridge, NAT, Host-only?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae The physical machine is connected to the internet with standard IPv4, with a wireless adapter

Comment: Guest, I asked about the guest

Comment: @user199464: **guest** = the virtual machine (VM), **host** = the physical machine VMs are running on

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the guest is using NAT

Comment: @Nick Updated my reply

Answer (score 1):

1) Use bridged mode, then you can simply ssh into the IP address of the guest machine, from anywhere in your LAN, and in particular from the host;

2) Add a second adapter, in the Host-only mode. Then you ill have two interfaces, one on the host and one in the guest, and you can ssh from one into the other. But no one else will be able to do likewise, from LAN or WAN.

3) There are several posts which claim the following method also works, with a single adapter. But though I can see ssh requests into the guest (by running ssh via the command

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
```

I have never been able to make it work. Perhaps you will...

In VirtualBox, VM's Network panel, click on Advanced -> Port Forwarding button. Now define  a rule with these values:

Host IP: 127.0.0.1
Host Port: 2222
Guest IP: 10.0.2.15
Guest Port: 22

Then enable ssh in the guest, and then use

ssh -p 2222 root@127.0.0.1

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51736887/centosfail.png doesnt really work for me